# Morphism of von Neumann Algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Hello,

Is there a counterexample to the following statement:
let $A,B$ two von Neumann algebras, every morphism $A \rightarrow B$ of $C^*  $-algebras is a $W^*$-homomorphism ?

( a $W^* $-homomorphism is a continuous morphism for the weak topologies $\sigma(A,A_* )$ and $\sigma(B,B_* )$, where $A_* $ and $B_* $ are the preduals)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $B$ to be the bidual of $A$ and take your morphism to be the canonical inclusion of $A$ into $A^{**}$.

Comment: Take any commutative von Neumann algebra A without atomic projections.  There are no W*-morphisms from A to complex numbers, yet there are many C*-morphisms of this type.  In fact, the Gelfand-Neumark theorem tells us that C*-morphisms distinguish different elements of A.

Comment: It might be worth adding that any C*-isomorphism between $A$ and $B$, if there is one, is also a W*-isomorphism.